# logistic regression,machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, logistic-regression, numpy, implementation

I just started learning ML, so I tried to implement logistic regression on my own in 2 ways (the first code and the second code), but they aren't working, I cross-checked by using sklearn (third code given below), could anyone help me in figuring out the mistake I have been doing. The link to the dataset used in this code is here [dataset](https://github.com/prathvikgs/ML_codes_beginner/blob/main/ex2data1.csv)

FIRST CODE vectorized implementation of logistic regression

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#sigmoid function
def sigmoid(z):

    a=1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    
    return a

#predicted y value for a given w,b ans x
def y_out(x_test,w_ini,b_ini):
    m,n=x_test.shape
    a=sigmoid(np.dot(w_ini,np.transpose(x_test))+b_ini)
    a=a.reshape(m,1)
    return a

#loss of a single training example
def loss(x_train,y_train,w_ini,b_ini):
    l=0
    l=-(y*np.log(y_out(x_train,w_ini,b_ini))+(1-y)*np.log(1-y_out(x_train,w_ini,b_ini)))
    
    return l

#the cost function
def cost(x,y,w,b):
    J=0
    m,n=x.shape
    J=(1/m)*np.sum(loss(x,y,w,b))
    
    return J

#derivative terms
def gradient(x_train,y_train,w_ini,b_ini):
    
    
    m,n=x_train.shape
    dw=np.zeros(n)
    dw=dw.reshape(len(dw),1)
    db=0.
    
    dw=(1/m)*(np.dot(np.transpose(x_train),y_out(x_train,w_ini,b_ini)-y_train))
    db=(1/m)*(np.sum(y_out(x_train,w_ini,b_ini)-y_train))
    
    dw=dw.reshape(1,len(dw))
    return dw,db


#gradient descent
def optimize(x_train,y_train,w_ini,b_ini,alpha,itirations):
    
    m,n=x.shape
    w=w_ini
    b=b_ini
    for i in range(itirations):
        
        dw,db=gradient(x_train,y_train,w,b)
        w=w-alpha*(dw)
        b=b-alpha*(db)
        
    return w,b
    



dataset=pd.read_csv("ex2data1.csv")
x=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
y=y.reshape(len(y),1)
m,n=x.shape

#initialization
w=np.zeros(n)
b=0.

#running the algoritm
w_out,b_out=optimize(x,y,w,b,1e-5,10000)

#parameters after running gradient descent
print(w_out,b_out)
```

SECOND CODE, Logistic regression using loops

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


#definition of the sigmoid function
def sigmoid(z):
    f=1/(1+(np.e)**-z)
    return f

#cost 
def cost(x,y,w,b):
    m,n=x.shape
    cost=0
    
    for i in range(m):
        cost_i=(-y[i]*(np.log(sigmoid(np.dot(w,x[i]))+b)))-((1-y[i])*(np.log(1-sigmoid(np.dot(w,x[i]))+b)))
        cost+=cost_i
        
    return cost/m
        
#gradient(derivatives)
def gradient(x,y,w,b):
    
    m,n=x.shape
    dj_dw=np.zeros(n)#derivative terms for each feature
    dj_db=0.
    
    for i in range(m):
        z_wb=np.dot(w,x[i])+b
        f_wb=sigmoid(z_wb)
        
        for j in range(n):
            dj_dw[j]+=(f_wb-y[i])*x[i][j]
        dj_db+=f_wb-y[i]
        
    dj_dw=dj_dw/m
    dj_db=dj_db/m
    
    return dj_dw,dj_db


#gradient descent
def gradient_descent(x,y,w_in,b_in,alpha,num_iters):
    
    m,n=x.shape
    w=w_in
    b=b_in
    for i in range(num_iters):
        
        dj_dw,dj_db=gradient(x,y,w,b)
        
        w=w-alpha*dj_dw
        b=b-alpha*dj_db
       
    
    return w,b    
        

#predicting
def predict(x,w,b):
    m,n=x.shape
    p=np.zeros(m)
    
    for i in range(m):
        z_wb=np.dot(w,x[i])+b
        f_wb=sigmoid(z_wb)
        
        if(p[i]>=0.5):
            p[i]=1
        else:
            p[i]=0
            
    return p
        

#preprocessing
dataset=pd.read_csv("ex2data1.csv")
x_train=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y_train=dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
y_train=y_train.reshape(len(y_train),1)



#initialization
m,n=x_train.shape
w=np.zeros(n)
b=0.


w_out,b_out=gradient_descent(x_train,y_train,w,b,1e-4,10000)


print(w_out)
print(b_out)

#predicting
y_pred=predict(x_train,w_out,b_out)
```

THIRD CODE,logistic regression using sklearn

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dataset=pd.read_csv("ex2data1.csv")
x=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,-1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=1)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc=StandardScaler()
x_train=sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test=sc.transform(x_test)


from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier=LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)


y_pred=classifier.predict(x_test)


from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score
cm=confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
print(cm)
accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)



print(classifier.coef_)
print(classifier.intercept_)
```